# What would be the proper syntax for the phrase- "The what now?" in response to some word they don't understand?

Tags: phrases

Like-
"This can easily be explained by the concept of quantum tunneling," he said.
Lara did a double-take. "The what now?"

> "The what now?"

is this correct?

Comment: I've never heard this expression. I'd expect "The concept of what?" / "What concept?" // "The _what_?" / "***What?*** (Not the more grammatical 'Which concept?') Or even the whacky "The who the where the why the what the which!?"

Comment: It's just a slightly different version of ***What's that, now?***, where the optional ***now*** is effectively an "intensifier", as in the exasperated ***Now** what?* response to continual pestering.

Comment: "The what …" would work.

"What now…" would work.

"The what now…" won't work in English.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the construction of the sentence in the question. (At least in terms of informal speech.)